# How to create a two-way peg ERC20 token?

Tags: erc-20

I was looking at the [Woofy token](https://github.com/yearn/woofy/blob/master/contracts/Woofy.vy), that is a two-way peg to YFI.

I don't use Vyper myself. I'm trying to understand how something like this is created.

How is it possible to create a token that is pegged to a percentage of another token?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is quite easy, for every YFI deposited the same amount of WOOFY are created. The YFI can be withdrawn but the same amount of WOOFY will be burned.

To be really sure you have to verify that there's no other way to create WOOFY tokens, or it is not possible to withdraw YFI without burning an equivalent amount of WOOFY.

From a quick look it appears WOOFY is a wrapper above YFI that implements [EIP 2612 Permit - 712-signed approvals](https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-2612).